# Laravel db query with now()

Tags: mysql, laravel

I need to take data from DB, but only when ReturnDate column represents date in the future.
When i do SQL query from DB its working 
SQL code:

```
SELECT * FROM `injuries_suspensions` WHERE `Type` = 'injury' and NOW() < `ReturnDate`
```

But when i use similar version in Laravel DB query builder, i dont get any data (when i erase where with NOW() i get all data so thats the problem)

Lravel code:

```
$injuries = DB::table('injuries_suspensions')->where('Type', '=', 'injury')->where(DB::raw('NOW()'), '<', 'ReturnDate')->get();
```

P.S
dates in DB are far in the future 2020-11-30.

Comment: What's the format of `ReturnDate`?

Comment: datetime, should i try with timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the simplified version `whereRaw` instead:

```
$injuries = DB::table('injuries_suspensions')
    ->where('Type', '=', 'injury')
    ->whereRaw('ReturnDate > NOW()')->get(); //see I changed the comparison sides
```

Observation is that, you're not using whereRaw properly: all should be inside a single string see [laravel's example](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions).

You can also pass the timestamp/date directly when building the query, using Carbon see:

```
use Carbon/Carbon;
....

$injuries = DB::table('injuries_suspensions')
    ->where('Type', '=', 'injury')
    ->where('ReturnDate', '>', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())->get();
```

> PS: Beware though of timezone difference of your db and your server.